# Ruby/ice_cube: Exclude whole day for hourly recurring event

Tags: ruby, recurring-events, ice-cube

Just started playing around with [ice_cube](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube) I've got a weekly schedule (with a granularity of half an hour) created

```
schedule = IceCube::Schedule.new(Time.now.change(:min => 30))
```

with several rules (let's say 20) such as e.g.

```
IceCube::Rule.weekly.day(:tuesday).hour_of_day(14).minute_of_hour(30)
```

or

```
IceCube::Rule.weekly.day(:wednesday).hour_of_day(10).minute_of_hour(0)
```

Now I'd like to exclude a full day, which would subsequently exclude all occurrences during this full day.

I've tried

```
schedule.add_exception_date [DATE]
```

but it seems that my exception has to match the event exactly.

*Is there a way to get this done without looping through all rules and creating exception for the exact times for the date specified?*

---

**Update:**

To make a better example:

```
Weekly schedule:
  * Every monday at 14:40
  * Every monday at 15:00
  * Every thursday at 16:00 
  * Every saturday at 10:00

Exception date:
  Tuesday, 13th of September 2011

=> For the week from Monday 12th to Sunday 18th I'd like to get only the occurrences on Thursday and Saturday.
```

One solution could look something like this, but it's a little icky:

```
schedule    = IceCube::Schedule.from_yaml([PERSISTED SCHEDULE])
occurrences = schedule.occurrences_between([START TIME], [END TIME])
exceptions  = schedule.exdates.map(&:to_date)
occurrences.reject {|occurrence|
  exceptions.include?(occurrence.to_date)
}
```

—Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there seems to be no other solution and in order to close this question, here’s what I'm using (as described in an update to the original question above already):

```
schedule    = IceCube::Schedule.from_yaml([PERSISTED SCHEDULE])
occurrences = schedule.occurrences_between([START TIME], [END TIME])
exceptions  = schedule.exdates.map(&:to_date)
occurrences.reject {|occurrence|
  exceptions.include?(occurrence.to_date)
}
```